# Authentication failed in Spoj

Tags: authentication

I created an account in spoj, and save my password for this site. But, when I login again, although my password and username are correct but it's login authentication and I can't enter it. I created the other account but it's too. So, what should I do?

Comment: same thing happening with me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are putting correct userid (not email) while logging in.

Answer (score 0):

login with a **username**, be sure that you're not trying to login with your e-mail with which you've registered.

And of-course, password.